# .Net assembly version mismatch

Tags: .net, asp.net

After a few check-ins and auto merges (on TFS) of an ASP .NET Web App, I have an assembly version mismatch:

> Assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2009.3.1314.35, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' **uses 'System.Web.Extensions,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly
>   'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0**, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Apparently, this means I should reference System.Web.Extensions version 3.5.0.0 instead of 1.0.61025.0.

I've removed and added the references to both assemblies multiple times, I've made sure there's no 1.0.61025.0 in the Web.config, I've also scanned the bin folder for anything that looks like System.Web.Extensions, but I can't find anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your project is targeting *.NET 3.5* and that there aren't any other assembly references to *System.Web.Extensions 1.0.61025.0* in your project or `bin` folders.

Comment: This solves the problem. The project wasn't using .NET 3.5. Thanks for saving me hours on this one!